# Elastic search different query norm across shards

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm rather new to ES and I have been studying scoring in ES in an attempt to improve the quality of search results. I have come across a situation in which the `queryNorm` function is very different (5X as large) across shards. I can see the dependency on the `idf` for the terms in the query, which can be different across shards. However, in my case, I have a single search term + the idf measure across shards are close to each other (definitely not enough to cause the X 5 times difference). I will briefly describe my setup, including my query and the result from the explain endpoint.

**Setup** 
I have an index with ~ 6500 docs which are distributed across 5 shards. I mention there are no index time boosts on the fields that appear in the query below. I mention my setup uses ES 2.4 with "query_then_fetch". My query:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [ {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [ ],
          "must_not" : [ ],
          "should" : [ {
                "multi_match" : {
                  "query" : "pds",
                  "fields" : [ "field1" ],
                  "lenient" : true,
                  "fuzziness" : "0"
                }
          }, {
                "multi_match" : {
                  "query" : "pds",
                  "fields" : [ "field2" ],
                  "lenient" : true,
                  "fuzziness" : "0",
                  "boost" : 1000.0
                }
          }, {
                "multi_match" : {
                  "query" : "pds",
                  "fields" : [ "field3" ],
                  "lenient" : true,
                  "fuzziness" : "0",
                  "boost" : 500.0
                }
          }, {
                "multi_match" : {
                  "query" : "pds",
                  "fields" : [ "field4" ],
                  "lenient" : true,
                  "fuzziness" : "0",
                  "boost": 100.0
                }
          } ],
      "must_not" : [ ],
      "should" : [ ],
      "filter" : [ ]
    }
  },
  "size" : 1000,
  "min_score" : 0.0
}
```

Explain output for 2 of the documents (one having query norm 5X times as large as the other one):

```
{
  "_shard" : 4,
  "_explanation" : {
    "value" : 2.046937,
    "description" : "product of:",
    "details" : [ {
      "value" : 4.093874,
      "description" : "sum of:",
      "details" : [ {
        "value" : 0.112607226,
        "description" : "weight(field1:pds in 93) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
        "details" : [ {
          "value" : 0.112607226,
          "description" : "score(doc=93,freq=1.0), product of:",
          "details" : [ {
            "value" : 0.019996,
            "description" : "queryWeight, product of:",
            "details" : [ {
              "value" : 2.0,
              "description" : "boost",
              "details" : [ ]
            }, {
              "value" : 5.6314874,
              "description" : "idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1232)",
              "details" : [ ]
            }, {
              "value" : 0.0017753748,
              "description" : "queryNorm",
              "details" : [ ]
            } ]
          }, {
            "value" : 5.6314874,
            "description" : "fieldWeight in 93, product of:",
            "details" : [ {
              "value" : 1.0,
              "description" : "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
              "details" : [ {
                "value" : 1.0,
                "description" : "termFreq=1.0",
                "details" : [ ]
              } ]
            }, {
              "value" : 5.6314874,
              "description" : "idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1232)",
              "details" : [ ]
            }, {
              "value" : 1.0,
              "description" : "fieldNorm(doc=93)",
              "details" : [ ]
            } ]
          } ]
        } ]
      }, {
        "value" : 3.9812667,
        "description" : "weight(field4:pds in 93) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
        "details" : [ {
          "value" : 3.9812667,
          "description" : "score(doc=93,freq=2.0), product of:",
          "details" : [ {
            "value" : 0.9998001,
            "description" : "queryWeight, product of:",
            "details" : [ {
              "value" : 100.0,
              "description" : "boost",
              "details" : [ ]
            }, {
              "value" : 5.6314874,
              "description" : "idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1232)",
              "details" : [ ]
            }, {
              "value" : 0.0017753748,
              "description" : "queryNorm",
              "details" : [ ]
            } ]
          }, {
            "value" : 3.9820628,
            "description" : "fieldWeight in 93, product of:",
            "details" : [ {
              "value" : 1.4142135,
              "description" : "tf(freq=2.0), with freq of:",
              "details" : [ {
                "value" : 2.0,
                "description" : "termFreq=2.0",
                "details" : [ ]
              } ]
            }, {
              "value" : 5.6314874,
              "description" : "idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1232)",
              "details" : [ ]
            }, {
              "value" : 0.5,
              "description" : "fieldNorm(doc=93)",
              "details" : [ ]
            } ]
          } ]
        } ]
      } ]
    }, {
      "value" : 0.5,
      "description" : "coord(2/4)",
      "details" : [ ]
    } ]
  }
},
{
  "_shard" : 2,
  "_explanation" : {
    "value" : 0.4143453,
    "description" : "product of:",
    "details" : [ {
      "value" : 0.8286906,
      "description" : "sum of:",
      "details" : [ {
        "value" : 0.018336227,
        "description" : "weight(field1:pds in 58) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
        "details" : [ {
          "value" : 0.018336227,
          "description" : "score(doc=58,freq=1.0), product of:",
          "details" : [ {
            "value" : 0.0030464241,
            "description" : "queryWeight, product of:",
            "details" : [ {
              "value" : 2.0,
              "description" : "boost",
              "details" : [ ]
            }, {
              "value" : 6.0189342,
              "description" : "idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1815)",
              "details" : [ ]
            }, {
              "value" : 2.5307006E-4,
              "description" : "queryNorm",
              "details" : [ ]
            } ]
          }, {
            "value" : 6.0189342,
            "description" : "fieldWeight in 58, product of:",
            "details" : [ {
              "value" : 1.0,
              "description" : "tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:",
              "details" : [ {
                "value" : 1.0,
                "description" : "termFreq=1.0",
                "details" : [ ]
              } ]
            }, {
              "value" : 6.0189342,
              "description" : "idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1815)",
              "details" : [ ]
            }, {
              "value" : 1.0,
              "description" : "fieldNorm(doc=58)",
              "details" : [ ]
            } ]
          } ]
        } ]
      }, {
        "value" : 0.81035435,
        "description" : "weight(field4:pds in 58) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
        "details" : [ {
          "value" : 0.81035435,
          "description" : "score(doc=58,freq=2.0), product of:",
          "details" : [ {
            "value" : 0.1523212,
            "description" : "queryWeight, product of:",
            "details" : [ {
              "value" : 100.0,
              "description" : "boost",
              "details" : [ ]
            }, {
              "value" : 6.0189342,
              "description" : "idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1815)",
              "details" : [ ]
            }, {
              "value" : 2.5307006E-4,
              "description" : "queryNorm",
              "details" : [ ]
            } ]
          }, {
            "value" : 5.3200364,
            "description" : "fieldWeight in 58, product of:",
            "details" : [ {
              "value" : 1.4142135,
              "description" : "tf(freq=2.0), with freq of:",
              "details" : [ {
                "value" : 2.0,
                "description" : "termFreq=2.0",
                "details" : [ ]
              } ]
            }, {
              "value" : 6.0189342,
              "description" : "idf(docFreq=11, maxDocs=1815)",
              "details" : [ ]
            }, {
              "value" : 0.625,
              "description" : "fieldNorm(doc=58)",
              "details" : [ ]
            } ]
          } ]
        } ]
      } ]
    }, {
      "value" : 0.5,
      "description" : "coord(2/4)",
      "details" : [ ]
    } ]
  }
}
```

Notice how the `queryNorm` on `field1` from the document in shard 4 is "0.0017753748" (with idf 5.6314874), while the `queryNorm` for the same field for doc in shard 2 is "0.0002.5307006" (with idf 6.0189342). I've tried to follow by hand the calculation for `queryNorm` using the formula on http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html , but failed to achieve the same answers.

I haven't seen too many threads / posts regarding calculating `queryNorm` ; one which I've found useful is http://www.openjems.com/tag/querynorm/ (this is actually Solr, but since the query is "query_then_fetch" ; the Lucene calculations should be the only thing that matter, so I expect they should behave similarly). However, I couldn't derive the right `queryNorm` values using the same approach (as fast as I understand, t.getBoost() should be 1 in my case since there are no index time field boosts + no special field boost in the query above).

Does anyone have any suggestion as to what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `search_type` to be equal `dfs_query_then_fetch`:

```
{
    "search_type": "dfs_query_then_fetch",
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [],
                        "must_not": [],
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "multi_match": {
                                    "query": "pds",
                                    "fields": [
                                        "field1"
                                    ],
                                    "lenient": true,
                                    "fuzziness": "0"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "multi_match": {
                                    "query": "pds",
                                    "fields": [
                                        "field2"
                                    ],
                                    "lenient": true,
                                    "fuzziness": "0",
                                    "boost": 1000.0
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "pds",
                        "fields": [
                            "field3"
                        ],
                        "lenient": true,
                        "fuzziness": "0",
                        "boost": 500.0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "pds",
                        "fields": [
                            "field4"
                        ],
                        "lenient": true,
                        "fuzziness": "0",
                        "boost": 100.0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [],
            "should": [],
            "filter": []
        }
    },
    "size": 1000,
    "min_score": 0.0
}
```

In this case all norm values will be global. But it may impact the query performance. If your index is small, you can also create an index with a single shard. But if you have much more documents, these values should be that different.

Comment: I tried the "dfs_query_then_fetch" option and the final scores didn't change much. Unfortunately, I can't seem to see the updated explanation, due to a bug in the explain endpoint https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15369 (this was fixed in august 2016 and my version is prior to that). My intuition is that something else is affecting the scoring as well.

Comment: Could you provide your request and response with `dfs_query_then_fetch` option? And what ES version do you have?